# Unable to change storage/framework permissions

Tags: php, laravel

I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong. I have been trying to work on the business logic of a Laravel application I am working on, but now I want to see my views in a browser, and no matter what I do I get an exception relating to the file permissions of storage/framework. The latest one is

> file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/Code/bitpaigow/storage/framework/sessions/VMdtCxzQwaGVremFgwFzj9HnNRkvKuDOMzUsWrXP): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have so far tried two different servers: Homestead and Laravel's serve command. What I understand is the problem now is my permissions. Homestead, hoping to allow access to those directories from my Laravel app, however, no matter what I do I always run into an error relating to these folders having the wrong permissions.

I have tried `chmod 777 storage/framework` but I still get the same error. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Try clearing out your sessions directory. Then doing a php artisan cache:clear and clearing your browser history then refreshing it.

Comment: in your confing file clear session file and also clear your browsing cache..and also history.

Comment: The error you show says the file or dir does not exist, that's not a permissions error. Does that directory actually exist?

Comment: I've tried deleting those files and clearing my cache. I am sure that the directory exists. I am able to output simple text but not views. I noticed a few days ago they for some reason were missing so I created them in sublime. I got a different error oh my Homestead server, will edit question and post it

Comment: Nevermind, I get the same error now

Answer (score -2):

```
chmod -R 777 storage/framework
```

```
update

chown nginx:nginx storage/framework
chown nginx:nginx storage/logs
```

change nginx:nginx with your user

Comment: Please don't do this, never, not even at a gunpoint.
The `storage/framework` directory hosts the `sessions` directory and other directories at well, by giving 777 permissions to this directory you're giving anyone on the server the ability to read, write, and execute anything that's in this directory.
For example, a script might be able to read users sessions from the folder raising the possibility of security risks.